How can I speed up CGAL::compute_intersection_points() without changing kernel into EPICK?
I want to calculate the intersection points between several polygons (including their vertices), more precisely the intersection points between their edges. I wrote the following pseudocode for doing so:
std::vector<Point_2> points;
edges <- collect all edges of every polygon;
CGAL::compute_intersection_points(edges.begin(), edges.end(), std::back_inserter(points), true);

The above code will be executed multiple times in my program, and the polygons will change after one iteration, so the previous calculation result cannot be reused in the next iteration.
I am using the default CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel with Lazy_exact_nt<> as my kernel. The exact number type is based on the boost::multiprecision backend.
I used Visual Studio profiling tools to analyze my CPU usage, and I found that function exact() in computd_intersection_points() takes up a lot of time (almost 40%).
profiling1
profiling2
I want to know if the cost of exact() is normal and if it can be accelerated. I also want to keep the result being exact, therefore the CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel will be the last choice. Furthermore, among a lot of number types in CGAL, which exact number type is more suitable for me to choose?

I wonder if the fact that the edges come from polygons (2 consecutive share a vertex) plays a role.

@MarcGlisse Thank you for your comment. Do you mean that I should set the flag of report_endpoint to false? I have tried but it has not worked.

I think you should provide a [mcve], i.e. a complete program (not pseudo-code), with a dataset (if needed), on which this exact() issue can be noticed, and that is as small as possible. Also, CGAL can use 2 different types from Boost.Multiprecision one using GMP+MPFR, and one not (you can probably look inside exact in the profile to see if it eventually goes into GMP or if everything remains inside boost).

@MarcGlisse Thank you for the advice.  It seems that I used pure boost::multiprecision instead of boost+gmp before. The issue with exact() seems to have been resolved after switching to boost+gmp as my backend. By the way, are there any performance differences between gmp and mpfr under Win64 and Linux?
